# Como comparar datas que vem de um arquivo CSV em Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

Bom pessoal tenho um arquivo CSV com alguns dados nele no caso esta:

```
Nome; Data; Salario

JOANNA  1981-04-11  7519.07
LUCIMAR 1958-06-10  819.77
PEDRO   1976-05-11  83.43    
JOAO    1989-03-12  867.5    
CAIO    1954-02-13  88.6   
JULIANA 1958-07-15  884.78    
LUCIMAR 1958-02-16  894.7
```

Queria saber como faço para comparar essas duas datas e saber qual é a maior e A menor e também saber o nome das pessoas que nasceram na mesma data alguém pode me dar uma luz. Sei que quando leio o arquivo CSV os dados vem em um array so que não estou conseguindo comparar as mesmas quem poder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Davi, a ideia geral do tens de fazer para atingir os teus objectivos é, primeiro tratar os dados:

1. Ler os dados do ficheiro data.csv
2. Deitar as duas primeiras linhas fora
3. Converter cada String para um Array com 3 Strings
4. Filtrar os dados que se quer: Deixar o nome das pessoas, converter a String com a data para um object do tipo Date, mandar os números fora.

Assim que os dados estiverem filtrados, so precisamos de os ordenar/agrupar da forma que pretendemos.

A snippet que resolve o teu problema é a seguinte:

```
require 'date'

# Ler e formatar dados
formated_data = File.readlines('data.csv')[2..-1]
  .map { |line| line.split()  }
  .map { |fields| [fields[0], Date.parse(fields[1])] }

# Agrupar e ordenar dados
# Maior data:
p formated_data.max_by{ |fields| fields[1] }

# Menor data:
p formated_data.min_by{ |fields| fields[1] }

# Pessoas nasceram na mesma data
p formated_data.group_by { |fields| fields[1] }
```

Agora vamos ver o que é que faz cada linha:

- Linha 1: `require 'date'` importa a classe `Date` da biblioteca standart do ruby [Docs: Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)
- Linha 3: `formated_data = File.readlines('data.csv')[2..-1]` Le cada linha do ficheiro 'data.csv' para um Array. De seguida mandamos as duas primeiras linhas fora. [Docs: IO.read_lines](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) e [Docs: Aceder a elementos de um Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements)
- Linha 4: Usar o método Array#map, para aplicar o método String#split a cada linha do ficheiro 'data.csv'. [Docs: Como Iterar dentro de Arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) e [Docs: String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)
- Linha 5: Criar um novo Array, apenas com o primeiro campo do Array inicial e transformar as strings tipo '1981-04-11' em objectos do tipo Date. [Docs: Converter strings para datas](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse)

Agora que já tens os dados transformados em objectos, é fácil transforma-los de forma a que eles se agrupem/filtrem da forma a que eles respondam ás tuas perguntas:

1. Para obter a data maxima, basta 'dizeres' que queres o máximo do array com o método `#max_by` e aplica-lo ao segundo campo array ( o que tem a data) . [Docs: max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)
2. A mesma coisa para o obteres o mínimo, mas usa antes o método `#min_by`. [Docs: min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by)
3. Finalmente para agrupares por data, usa o método #group_by. [Docs: #group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)